# xcode still displaying version error after updating to 10.15

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm new to xcode, and when I opened the hello-world application and compiled I was faced with these errors since I was on macOS 10.14:

[image]

I've since updated to 10.15 but I still get the same errors when I run the code, even though it successfully builds and outputs the 'hello world' application. I've made sure that my deployment target is 10.15 (not 10.14), but I still am stuck with the errors. How do I get the errors to go away ?

Comment: what kind of hello world app has an NSHostingView?

Comment: If the project successfully builds and runs, there are no errors to fix. Xcode is showing stale error messages that no longer exist. If seeing the errors bothers you, choose Product > Clean Build Folder and rebuild the project. The stale compiler errors should go away.